# Galaxy Tab A (7.1.1) Refuses to Root

Tags: root-access, kingo

I'm using Kingo Root, but it keeps stopping at 90% and giving me error code 0x12B263. I've tried iRoot, Kingo, and many more but they've all failed. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use a computer to phone based soultion. One touch rooting apps use a exploit that has since been patched.

Answer (score 0):

As said by another buddy here, the exploitation used by the one click rooter has bed patched. Try **One Click Root**, it's exploits are updated often. (**Requires PC**)
If still no luck there's two **HARD WAYS**. I wouldn't suggest this'd for regular user, and I take no responsibility if device is bricked.

The two ways are:

- **With a Linux**: Get any small linux, put device into recovery mode. You'll be able to browse system files of your device. Download a **SuperSU Flashable Zip**. Extract the "**su**"," **busybox**","**Superuser.apk**" from **arm7** folders in the zip. Copy "**su**"," **busybox**" into **/system/bin** and **/system/xbin**. Then copy **Superuser.apk** into **/system/app/**. Reboot the Device.
- Recovery Flash: Search for how to flash **TWRP** on

***[I TAKE NO RESPONSIBILITY OF YOUR DEVICE IF YOU BRICK IT, IT'S ALL IN YOUR HANDS]***

*[BTW AS PER ME, EVEN HARD BRICK CAN BE FIXED FOR A **FEW PHONES**]*

Good Luck